# creating a array from multiple multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created following array. But this is not what actually i want. help to create a new array from this to fulfill my requirements.

```
Array (
[supplier_id] => 1
[filter_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => product 1 
        [1] => Product 2
        [2] => Product 3
    )

[quantity] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 2
    )

[unit] => Array
    (
        [0] => pkts
        [1] => ltrs
        [2] => pkts
    )

[price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 100
        [2] => 10
    )

[gross_amount] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
        [1] => 1000
        [2] => 20
    )

[vat] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
    )

[net_amount] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
        [1] => 1000
        [2] => 20
    ) )
```

And This is the array i want exactly. Is there any idea to create this type of array.

```
Array(
[supplier_id] = 1
[0] = Array(
    [filter_name] => product 1
    [quantity] => 3
    [unit] => pkts
    [price] => 11
    [gross_amount] => 33
    [vat] => 0
    [net_amount] => 33
)
[1] = Array(
    [filter_name] => product 2
    [quantity] => 10
    [unit] => ltrs
    [price] => 100
    [gross_amount] => 1000
    [vat] => 0
    [net_amount] => 1000
)

[2] = Array(
    [filter_name] => product 3
    [quantity] => 2
    [unit] => pkts
    [price] => 10
    [gross_amount] => 20
    [vat] => 0
    [net_amount] => 20
))
```

Comment: Idea - use `foreach`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Can you post your script to help us understand where the data come from and how you tried to transform it? As @u_mulder said, a `foreach` could be a good start.

Comment: @u_mulder.. i can't use foreach becoz i have only a database table for this array. means i have to use 7 times foreach loop and every time insert/update the table value.

Comment: Any script how to use foreach loop here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you, I am assuming there are maximum 3 values in your sub-array, So I used `while($i<3);`

```
$i = 0;
   $newArray = array();
   do{
   foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
       if($key == 'supplier_id'){
            $newArray[$key] = $val;
        }else{
            $newArray[$i][$key] = $val[$i];
        }

   }
   $i++;   
   }while($i<3);
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArray);
```

[Check Output here](https://3v4l.org/j49Qe)

Comment: Glad to help :)